# Standard way with for `@JSExportTopLevel` when Exporting under a namespace in `scala-js 1.x.x`

Tags: scala, scala.js

I have two classes with the same name **A** having different package one as: -

```
xxx.yyy.v1.A
```

and second as:-

```
xxx.yyy.v2.A
```

I have to use **@JSExportTopLevel** in scala-js (1.1.1).

**What is the standard way of accomplishing this?**

Previously in scala-js (0.6.x), I used something like this: -

```
@JSExportTopLevel("xxx.yyy.v1.A")
```

and

```
@JSExporttopLevel("xxx.yyy.v2.A")
```

but with scala-js (1.1.1 ), it is now removed.  [Exporting under a namespace (deprecated)](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/export-to-javascript.html)

Note:- I am facing this issue in scala-js upgrade **0.6.x** -> **1.x.x**

My configuration: -

**scala** -> 2.13.3, **jvm** -> 14, **sbt** -> 1.3.13, **scala-js** -> 1.x.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exporting under a namespace was [deprecated in Scala.js 0.6.26](https://www.scala-js.org/news/2018/11/29/announcing-scalajs-0.6.26/) and eventually removed in 1.x because such exports do not correspond to anything in terms of ECMAScript module `export`s. The compiler had to jump through non-standard hoops to make them appear to work.

As the release notes of 0.6.26, linked above, explain, the replacement is to explicitly construct a JS object that will hold those namespaces and the values to export. In your case:

```scala
object JSNamespacesExports {
  @JSExportTopLevel("xxx")
  val xxx = new js.Object {
    val yyy = new js.Object {
      val v1 = new js.Object {
        val A = _root_.xxx.yyy.v1.A
      }

      val v2 = new js.Object {
        val A = _root_.xxx.yyy.v2.A
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(`_root_.` is used to force resolving `xxx` as a top-level Scala package, instead of the `val xxx` that is in scope.)

With this encoding, you explicitly choose how you want `xxx` to appear, as seen from JavaScript. This is more transparent than the opaque, half-baked implementation that Scala.js 0.6.x was using.